# Lookup construction using data matrix and Reap/Sow versus AppendTo`s

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-review

I am a user of MMA9 and made my own kind of Lookup, which is now a standard command in Version 10.

In my program there is a section in which by means of a StringReplace[ ]-command containing a lot of rules the necessary work is done really very fast.

I tried to do the same in the following way but this appears to be very slow (a factor of 10).

```
tabel[n_] := Table[{k, k, k, k, k, k}, {k, 1, n}];
tblhoogteABg = 434; ABg = tabel@tblhoogteABg;
dABg = Import["ABbis2175B(434)klaar.xlsx"];
eABg = Partition[Flatten[dABg], 5] // Transpose;
Do[ABg[[i, j]] = ToString[ eABg[[j]][[i]]], {i, 1, tblhoogteABg}, {j, 1, 3}];
Do[ABg[[i, j]] = ToExpression[ eABg[[j]][[i]]], {i, 1, tblhoogteABg}, {j, 4, 5}]
```

The items of colums 1,2 and 3 are String, those of colums 4 and 5 are Expressions (lists).

```
fff = ABg[[433, 2]];
rl = fff // ToExpression; 
ffr = {};
ll = Length[rl];   
Do[ 
   Do[rlp = rl[[el]]; (* rlp is a part of rl *)
     If[rlp == (ABg[[m, 1]] // ToExpression), 
        ffr = (ffr~AppendTo~ABg[[m, 5]]) // ToExpression // Flatten], 
 {el,1,ll}], {m, 1, tblhoogteABg}]; 
Print[fff, "->", ffr]
```

fff is a string in column 2 of ABg[[ , ]] and this is changed into a list rl = fff//ToExpression and transformed into ffr.

ffr is build up via a series of ffr~AppendTo~ABg[[m, 5]] commands, as many as there are parts rlp in rl, a list with length ll.

The row number m is found via the If-statement (the actual lookup part).

The result is:

```
{25B,75A,725B}->{151,12301,1451,5315701,17431901,
 199005929846082820906192074956026987594151}
```

I learned in some Q&A discussion concerning Reap and Sow that the combination of them is more efficient than the AppendTo-commands.

However, up to now I did not succeed in using Reap and Sow in the above fragment. I hope that someone can give me some help and that this method appears to be more rapid.

Comment: Don't have time to pull the code apart but some general comments: Always try to work with entire lists rather than looping through them as you are doing here. `AppendTo` is very slow. For one offs it might be acceptable but you are doing this operation 434 times. Faster options are functions like `Join` and `Flatten`. For the latter it is often faster to simply create flattened lists and partition at the end.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks for the comment! I replaced the ApppendTo`s with (ffr~Join~ABg[[m, 5]])// Sort. No speed difference was noticed. You must know there are in the data at the most three different parts for an ffr!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding elements to a growing list is slow in general. We get much better performance out of *Mathematica* if we treat data in chunks, and use high level functions as much as we can. This usually translates to a functional style of programming, as opposed to procedural programming. `Do`, `While` and `For` as therefore best to try to avoid altogether, in favor of `Nest`, `Map` and `Apply`.

As I understand it your code can be written like this (cannot tell whether it has bugs or not without sample data):

```
createTable[n_] := Table[{k, k, k, k, k, k}, {k, 1, n}];

numberOfRows = 434;
table = createTable[numberOfRows];

data = Import["ABbis2175B(434)klaar.xlsx"];
data = Partition[Flatten[data], 5];

table = MapAt[ToString, data, {All, {2, 3}}];
table = MapAt[ToExpression, data, {All, {1, 4, 5}}];

fff = table[[433, 2]];

fffElements = ToExpression@fff;
fffLength = Length@fffElements;
results = Flatten[Last /@ Select[table[[All, {1, 5}]], MemberQ[fffElements, First@#] &],2];

Print[fff, "->", results]
```

Basically, as you can see, `Part` (`[[ ]]`) and `Map` are the workhorses now rather than `Do`. There are probably things I would have written differently if I had the file, but the main idea is evident in this piece of code.

I don't know if this helps you. I'm kind of asking you to adopt a new programming paradigm... but it's **the** way to get more performance out of *Mathematica*.

But I've also been thinking about how I can address your actual question, that is, how can `Sow` be incorporated? I think this should work:

```
ffr = Last@Reap@Do[
     rlp = rl[[el]];(*rlp is a part of rl*)
     If[
      rlp == (ABg[[m, 1]] // ToExpression),
      Sow[ABg[[m, 5]] // ToExpression // Flatten]
      ],
     {el, 1, ll}, {m, 1, tblhoogteABg}
     ];
```

Comment: First of all my compliments for your excellent playing chess blindfold.  At the moment I do not have a site with FTP possibilities so I cannot provide the xlsx-file.
Your proposal is not completely working as it should. 
1) You overlooked a minor detail in my procedural approach. I had to remove the Transpose@ just before the Partition-command.
2) The line with results is not working. The three parts of fff should be looked up in column 1 and from the three found unique rows the items in colum 5 should be Joined together. I am still trying to find a repair. Perhaps you see it at once.

Comment: Your suggestion for Reap/Sow works fine! I only had to add a Flatten to the second level around Sow. Thanks.

Comment: @Rombert You're very welcome, the mistake with result was simple: I had to replace `First` with `Last` and `data` with `table`. I've also changed two other lines to something that may be more efficient.

Comment: I edited two things in order to make var `results` working: 1) table=MapAt[ToString,data,{All,{2,3}}]; (n.b. 2nd arg of MapAt put back to data) 2) table=MapAt[ToExpression,table,{All,{1,4,5}}]; First column should become ToExpression. Hope you will/can approve (;)

Comment: @Rombert Sorry, I understand now that my update yesterday was not correct. I've now updated again with a version of what I had to begin with. The original version also had a problem, but I hope I fixed that with my update. Because the `MapAt` thing doesn't correspond to exactly what the original code does.

Comment: I am also Sorry, I accidentally edited your answer post, it was rejected. But what I did is still stated in my comment before this one. It worked then as it should work but for a needed Flatten to the second level. I did not mention this in my comment nor did I edit it. I put a Flatten[  , 2] around the variable `result`. By the way, your last version does not yet work. (The first column of table MUST be ToExpression in stead of ToString. I hope this will not become a never-ending story (;-)

Comment: @Rombert It's alright if this story becomes longer, but you say it worked for you so I changed it back to what you suggested in your edit. You did the right thing by editing the working code into the answer, it was automatically rejected when I added my new version. I wrote my new version because I didn't think your suggestion was doing the same thing as the original code (you can see f.e. that `createTable` is not really used anymore), but if it works it works :)